# Add external Java library in Foundry

Tags: java, build.gradle, shared-libraries, palantir-foundry

I'm trying to add an external Java library to my Foundry repository, but I'm getting a little blocked on how to actually obtain the rid for the library (required to configure the gradle file properly). The library is transforms-excel-parser-bundle. At present, there is no direct link to the given library from from the settings > library view (where all other linked repositories / libraries are held). Any advice how I can hunt down the rid for this library so that I can add the necessary info to the gradle file in my own repo? Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.